# $A^TCA \leq B^TCB \Rightarrow A^TA \leq B^TB$?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$,$B \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $C=D^TD$ where $D$ is a $n\times n$ psd matrix, is it guaranteed that $A^TCA \leq B^TCB \Rightarrow A^TA \leq B^TB$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C = D^{T}D$,and we have all eigenvalues of $C$ are great than $0$ ,which means $> 0$.

Assume the eigenvector  $x$ and $y$of $C$ corresponding to $\lambda$ and $\mu$,respectively,and we have 
\begin{equation}
C x=\lambda x 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
C y =\mu y
\end{equation}
,which mean

\begin{equation}
x^{T} C x \leq y^{T} C y \rightarrow \lambda x^{T}x \leq \mu y^{T}y 
\end{equation}.

because that we don't know the relations between $ \lambda $ and $\mu$,even more we have known both,and then we can't identify which is bigger between $x^{T}x$ and $y^{T}y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
C =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 9
\end{array}
\right),
$$
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2  \\
0 
\end{array}
\right),
$$
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0  \\
1 
\end{array}
\right),
$$